# Where / What is the Package Explorer in Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to get hidden files to show in Eclipse (namely, a .htaccess file), and the answers point to doing something in the 'Package Explorer'. I'm using Eclipse PDT 2.1 and it's not apparent to me what / where that is. How do I get to this fabled 'Package Explorer' ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in this [102degrees blog entry](http://www.102degrees.com/blog/2007/07/11/show-the-right-files-in-php-explorer/):

> After I installed Eclipse PDT, I had two project navigators.
>   I closed the native one and kept open the PHP Explorer.
>   PHP Explorer showed my php, css, js, etc, files. It also puts a plus sign to the left of the filenames. Using this view, we can expand the file to see the classes and functions inside of the file without opening it.
>
> The only issue was that, by default, I couldn’t see my `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files.
>   On the bright side, using SVN, I couldn’t see my `.svn` folders - which is exactly what I wanted. Put, this put the issue into a different light - there must be some sort of filter that is restricting files that begin with a dot.
>
> At the top of the PHP Explorer, there are a few toolbar buttons.
>   Clicking the down arrow brings up a context menu.
>   I choose the `filters…` menu item. By default, ‘`name filter patterns`’ was not checked.
>   .* files and server projects were selected in the second box. This makes sense why I was not seeing my .htaccess file.

[alt text http://opensource.kruxgames.com/torquedit/torqueditDocs/torquedit_html_m6c4621c0.jpg](http://opensource.kruxgames.com/torquedit/torqueditDocs/torquedit_html_m6c4621c0.jpg)

> First, I unchecked my option .* files. This fixed the issue - I was able to see the `.htaccess` files - but I also saw my `.svn` folders as well as additional meta files.
>
> I checked the box saying “`name filter patterns`” and put in the following string:

```
.cache, .settings, .svn, .project, .projectOptions
```

---

As detailed in [xcc](http://musetracks.instantspot.com/blog/2007/09/13/Add-Custom-File-Filters-to-the-Eclipse-Explorer):

For plugins which do not offer a `name filter pattern` through GUI, one can:

> 1. Locate the directory of the Eclipse plugin being used for editing. This is usually something like `eclipse/plugins/[plugin name]_[version]`.
> 2. Open the plugin.xml file in a text editor.
> 3. Find the extension element whose point attribute has a value of `org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceFilters`.
> 4. Create a new filter element like any others that already exist, but containing the needed file pattern.
> 5. Restart Eclipse using the -clean switch.
>
> If the plugin.xml file didn't contain any resource filters, create one by adding the following code to the bottom of plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceFilters">
   <filter selected="false" pattern=".svn"></filter>
   <filter selected="false" pattern=".project"></filter>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Package Explorer can be displayed
>   in your workspace by going to the
>   Window>Show View>Other... menu,
>
> then unfold the *Java* Folder,click
>   *Package Explorer* and OK. It should show up as a tab in your
>   "Perspective".
>
> You probably found out what to do
>   next, but just in case: View
>   Menu(little arrow on the right) ->
>   Filters -> uncheck .* resources.

Edit: Now that I've read your question again, this doesn't apply to you, as the Package Explorer is used in the Java Perspective.

You are probably using the "PHP Explorer" View (Tab) to browse your files, which hides system files. To view all files from your project, use the *Navigator* view:
Window>Show View>Other...>Basic>Navigator .

Comment: This might sound a bit nuts, but the 'Java' folder doesn't exist in my list of views available, even after getting the new window by clicking 'other'. I have General, CVS, Data Management, Debug, Dynamic Languages, Help, Javascript, PHP Tools, Server, Team, and XML.